# Microsoft excel: Finding start and finish times where several time periods they overlap

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope someone can assist.... I need to get the start and finish time of overlapping times.
For example my first column's time periods are:
8:00 - 10:00
12:00 - 14:00
16:00 - 18:00

The second column is 9:00 - 13:00.

I need to get the start and finish times where the first column's times fall within the second column ie. Answer would be:
9:00 - 10:00
12:00 - 13:00

Please help!!

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your data, e.g., screenshot? This should also include your expected output.

Comment: How do you want to output the result in cells?

Comment: "8:00 - 10:00 12:00 - 14:00 16:00 - 18:00" <-- which cells contain which value?

Answer (score 0):

For the times given in the original post, this works:

1. In the LA (Left A) column: =LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" - ",A2)-1)+0
2. In the RA column: =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-(SEARCH(" - ",A2)+2))+0
3. In the LB column: =LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" - ",B2)-1)+0
4. In the RB column: =RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-(SEARCH(" - ",B2)+2))+0
5. In the Start column: =IF(AND(E2<C2,F2>C2),C2,IF(AND(E2<D2,F2>D2),E2,IF(AND(F2>C2,F2<D2),F2,"")))
6. In the End column: =IF(G2="","",IF(D2-G2<F2-G2,D2,F2))
   [image]